# jQuery validation did not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a very typical example of jQuery validation form but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" required and 13 or larger.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form" action="">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" size="50">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address" size="50">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="message">Message</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" cols="52" class="span5" placeholder="The message you want to send to us."></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <?php
                $var1 = rand(1,20);
                $var2 = rand(1,20);
                $sum = $var1 + $var2;
            ?>
            <label class="control-label" for="captcha">Please enter the result of <?php echo $var1.' + '.$var2.' ='; ?>
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha"><br/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
            <button type="submit" name="contact-submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Message</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            }
            captcha: {
                required: true,
                min: <?php echo $sum; ?>,
                max: <?php echo $sum; ?>
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        });
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            min: jQuery.validator.format("Wrong answer."),
            max: jQuery.validator.format("Wrong answer.")
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The only one thing needs to pay attention is my simple captcha. I use 2 php variables and its sum to check whether a spammer try to contact.
When I click on Submit button, the browser just refresh and nothing else happen, no error was generated. However, clicking Cancel button allow me to reset the form.
I have already searched for existing question relating to why jQuery validation did not work but can not figure out my case. Please help me to solve it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: You should at least tell us why it doesn't work, what errors are you getting. Otherwise anyone willing to help would need to put together a webserver and a php backend.

Comment: Is it because you use `$sum` before you define it? Look at the generated HTML and in the browser's error console.

Comment: Thank you for all help. I have just edited my question to make it easier to understand and moved js code block to the end of file to fix    $sum    definition that Juhana mentioned. However it still not work.

Comment: Look in the browser's error console. Are there any errors there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestion from @Juhana, I worked around with my code and found another way to make my code work. I just replaced:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            min: jQuery.validator.format("Wrong answer."),
            max: jQuery.validator.format("Wrong answer.")
```

by

```
messages: {
            captcha: {
                min: "Wrong answer",
                max: "Wrong answer"
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking it because you've placed `jQuery.extend()` inside of the `.validate()` method; and you've improperly included a closing parenthesis and semicolon where there can only be a comma.

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
    // options...
    ....,
    success: function (element) {
        ....
    }); // <- ');' is not valid here.  Options must be separated by commas
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {  // <- this is not a valid option!
        min: jQuery.validator.format("Wrong answer."),
        max: jQuery.validator.format("Wrong answer.")
    });
});
```

Only **[the options provided by the developer](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)** can go inside of the `.validate()` method.

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
    // options...
    ....,
    success: function (element) {
        ....
    }, // <- options must be separated by commas
    messages: { // <- valid option
        captcha: {
            min: "Wrong answer",
            max: "Wrong answer"
        }
    }
});
```